# IKImageView loses its focus for drag and drop when it is enclosed by NSScrollView

Tags: macos, cocoa, ikimageview

I Have an `IKImageView` enclosed by `NSScrollView` and a `NSSlider` for zooming the image in and out. `IKImageView` Supports drag and drop when the image is in normal size, but it loses its focus when the image is zoomed in. (If I scroll the `IKImageView` to the bottom left corner it supports drag and drop). How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accept the `NSDragOperation` though the `NSScrollView` instead of the `IKImageView`.
Next update the `IKImageView` from the `NSScrollView` subclass.